Quasar constantly stating config change when running on capacitor targeting android
I'm not to sure why this is now failing as it was working fine the other day.
It works fine when running as quasar dev but when I test on an android device I either get webpage not found or it doesn't load as it is continusly saying the quasar.config file has been updated and reloads.
I tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling. Done this with changing node versions also. I've tried quasar clean, build etc and still nothing.
I've tried backing up the .quasar folder to try and reset that but still get the issues.
